# pyenv cannot copy anaconda packages to an anaconda virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, anaconda, pyenv

1, I had a new linux with python=python2.7 and python3=python3.4

2, I installed pyenv by using git

3, I installed anaconda3-4.1.1 by using pyenv and set it as global via pyenv by using pyenv global anaconda3-4.1.1

4, I created a virtualenv  by using **pyenv virtualenv anaconda3-4.1.1 mytestenv**

5, I use import numpy to test the result. In the **original anaconda3-4.1.1** env it's OK for importing numpy, but in the **mytestenv** env there is no numpy.

Please see the details following:

```
(anaconda3-4.1.1) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ pyenv versions
  system
* anaconda3-4.1.1 (set by /home/giza/.pyenv/version)
(anaconda3-4.1.1) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ pyenv virtualenv anaconda3-4.1.1         mytestenv
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment         /home/giza/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.1.1/envs/mytestenv:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    openssl:    1.0.2j-0
    pip:        8.1.2-py35_0
    python:     3.5.2-0
    readline:   6.2-2
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py35_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0
    tk:         8.5.18-0
    wheel:      0.29.0-py35_0
    xz:         5.2.2-0
    zlib:       1.2.8-3

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##########################################################################################################| 100%
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# $ source activate mytestenv
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# $ source deactivate
#
Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py...
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/giza/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-    4.1.1/envs/mytestenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
(anaconda3-4.1.1) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ pyenv activate mytestenv
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(mytestenv) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> exit()
(mytestenv) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ pyenv deactivate
(anaconda3-4.1.1) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> exit()
(anaconda3-4.1.1) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed numpy while mytestenv was activated?

Comment: Why do you ask this? I do the "pyenv activate mytestenv" and then the PROMPT has been changed to "(mytestenv) giza@DESKTOP-H8KC9QC:~$ python" when I type the python.

Comment: Yes, but how did you install numpy? Activate your virtualenv, then type conda install numpy.